# AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'randhiletter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I am getting the error, **in the title**, even though there is a function randhiletter in the python file test.py. I am using this code in the file accessing test.py:

```
import test
print(test.randhiletter())
```

The code in test.py basically uses randint to assign a variable a number. Based on that number it will return a letter. There are two functions in test.py. These are randhiletter and randlowletter which do the same thing but for lowercase and uppercase letters. I do not understand why I am getting the error.

Comment: Pick a name that's not `test` and see if that fixes things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to user2357112 supports Monica for this answer. He/she did not post one so I felt that I should to close the discussion or something:
The issue was that I could not use the name test for the file I was trying to import as that is apparently already a python library.

Comment: Yeah, when you `import test` also check that `test.__path__` is the same module as you looking for.